# How do I set/give the parent node its children, its children's children, and so forth in Java?

Tags: java, nodes

I have a class `EightPuzzle`.

```
public class EightPuzzle {

int[][] board = new int[3][3];
//code here
}
```

Where I have a class `Node<T>` where `T` is of object `EightPuzzle`. If I have one `Node<EightPuzzle> parent`, how do I set its children? Its children's children? And so forth if the children are of `ArrayList<Node<EightPuzzle>>`?

```
public class Node<T> {

private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
private Node<T> parent = null;
private T data = null;

public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = parent;
}

public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
    parent.addChild(this);
    setParentInternal(parent);
}
public void setParentInternal(Node<T> parent){
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void addChild(T data) {
    addChild(new Node<T>(data));
}
public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
    child.setParentInternal(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

//may not use this and set data
public T getData() {
    return this.data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public boolean isRoot() {
    return (this.parent == null);
}

public boolean isLeaf() {
    if(this.children.size() == 0) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

public void removeParent() {
    this.parent = null;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get/set?

Comment: trying to set the parent.children with an Object EightPuzzle and setting their children etc

Comment: Have you tried creating `Node` objects and linking them together with `addChild` or `setParent`? I don't understand where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely to want to use a recursive method for something like below.

**Example:**

```
public void assignChildren(Node node) {
    List<Node> children = ... // somehow decide the children here
    node.setChildren(children);

    // This is just a for each loop using a java 8 method reference 
    // to make a recursive call 
    children.forEach(this::assignChildren); 
}
```

EDIT: 
Moved comment into answer

If you can't add a `setChildren(...)` method to your class then you can always just iterate over the children adding them to the node one by one

Comment: Sorry that answer came in drips and drabs submitted accidentally when I was only half way done. If you can't add a ```setChildren(...)``` method to your class then you can always just iterate over the children adding them to the node one by one

Comment: You need the base case of the recursion.

Comment: If there's things you need to add, you can edit your answer.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly the base case is implicit in the method I gave. Think about it like this when ```children``` is an empty list there is will no recursive call as the ```forEach(...)```  will do nothing

Comment: `children.forEach(this::setChildren);` doesn't really make any sense. The `this::setChildren` has the wrong signature, and it's not actually traveling down the structure because you called it on `this`.

Comment: @4castle it would actually work here is what it translates to ```for(T child : children){this.setChildren(child)}```.  But you have pointed out to me that I have two methods with the same name which is ambiguous. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: `T` doesn't have a `setChildren` method. This looks like an infinite loop. It never calls the method recursively on the child nodes. It still doesn't make sense.